# what is the difference in the syntax to capture the bash output?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, tee

I usually use

```
./aaa.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log
```

But found a new command which seems easier:

```
./aaa.sh &> log
```

**So what am I giving up in the second case?**

Comment: They're not comparable at all. The whole point of `tee` is to duplicate the input. If the goal isn't to duplicate the input, don't use `tee`.

Comment: Its worth remembering that `tee` is named because it functions sort of like a ["T" pipe fitting](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81gzAcGTwdL._SX385_.jpg) - i.e. 1 input - 2 outputs.  It even says so in the manpage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apples and oranges. But first...

As far as `2>&1` vs `&>`, they both act to direct *stderr* to the same place that *stdout* is being directed to.

But you are giving up portability with the second one as it is not POSIX-compliant and any script using it will only work with those shells that support it.

That being said they are "semantically equivalent" as described on the Bash man page...

> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard
>   error:
>
> ```
>       &>word    and
>       >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
>       >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> When  using  the  second  form, word may not expand to a number or
>   -.  If it does, other redirection    operators apply (see Duplicating File Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

However there's more to it. You also are using the `tee` command which adds additional functionality to the first version. It will take its *stdin* input and direct it to two different places: *stdout* (usually your screen/terminal if you're running this interactively) and the specified file which will have the data *appended* to it (`-a` says to append rather than overwrite).

Compare this to the second version where the combined *stdout* and *stderr* overwrite the `log` file and do not get displayed on your screen/terminal.

Conclusion: As mentioned at the beginning these are really two different commands altogether but, stretching the notion of equivalence, *generally speaking* the first version is superior as it is portable *and*  you get the benefit of seeing the output of `aaa.sh` even while it is being saved to a file. Of course, if you don't want to see that or you want to erase the previous file contents then it's a different story. Apples and oranges.

Comment: And of course a big advantage of `tee` is that prints *both* to the screen and file.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- `tee` prints its input to both the named file, *and* the standard output, in practice to your terminal. A straight redirection like `>` or `&>` only causes the file to be written.
- `tee -a` *appends* to the named file, a `>` or `&>` redirection overwrites it. Use `>>` or `&>>` or `>> file 2>&1` to append with a redirection.